# How to prove that there are no vector-valued function $\,f(x),g(y)$ satisfying $\langle f(x),g(y)\rangle = 1/(x+y)^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\,f(x),g(y) : \mathbb{R} \to {\mathbb{R}}^k$ where $x \in (0,1) ,\, y \in (0, \infty) $

I want to prove that
there are no functions $f(x),g(y)$ satisfying $\langle f(x),g(y) \rangle = \frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$

Comment: How is the inner product defined? Is it in terms of integrals or is it just a "general" inner product?

Comment: Yes, it just a "general" inner product.
That is <a,b> = a_1*b_1 + ... + a_k*b_k

Comment: Oh of course I completely misinterpreted the question.